# Consulta UPDATE con GROUP BY me da error

Tags: mysql

Cuando ejecuto el código me da error por el `GROUP BY` y a la hora de ponerlo en el código me dice que no es el lugar.

He visto por Internet que en distintos `INNER JOIN`, pero no lo entiendo a la hora de hacerlo.

**Enunciado:**

> 4.- Incrementa en 5 unidades el descuento de los clientes que han tenido 3 o más citas en 2022, siempre y cuando no tengan ya un descuento superior a 60. (Debes hacerlo con una única sentencia).

**Código SQL:**

```
UPDATE CLIENTE
 SET descuento=descuento+5 
 WHERE COUNT(CITA)>3 
 AND YEAR = 2022
 AND SUM(Descuento)< 60
 GROUP BY descuento;
```

**Esquema de las tablas:**

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS PROFESIONALES (
    numero_trabajador char(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    DNI char(9),
    especialidad varchar(60),
    nombre varchar(20),
    apellidos varchar(60),
    telefono char(9),
    estado varchar(20) check (estado in('Trabajando','Ausente','Despedido')),
    hora_inicio time,
    hora_fin time
);
create table IF NOT EXISTS CLIENTE (
    DNI char(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(60),
    apellidos varchar(60),
    telefono char(9),
    descuento smallint,
    baja varchar(2) check (baja in('si','no'))
);

create table IF NOT EXISTS CITA (
    numero_fisio char(5),
    DNI_cliente char(9),  
    a_domicilio varchar(2) check (a_domicilio in('si','no')),
    duracion time,
    fecha date,
    hora time,
    precio decimal(6,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(numero_fisio,DNI_cliente, fecha, hora),
    CONSTRAINT DNI_CLI_FK FOREIGN KEY (DNI_cliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE(DNI) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT CIT_NF_FK FOREIGN KEY (numero_fisio) REFERENCES FISIOTERAPEUTA(numero_trabajador_fisio) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

create table IF NOT EXISTS SALAS (
    codigo char(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre varchar(30),
    dimension tinyint
);

create table IF NOT EXISTS imparte (
    numero_trabajador_pilates char(5),
    codigo_sala char(3),
    fecha date,
    hora time,
    PRIMARY KEY(numero_trabajador_pilates,codigo_sala, fecha, hora),
    CONSTRAINT IMP_PIL_FK FOREIGN KEY (numero_trabajador_pilates) REFERENCES PROFESOR_PILATES(numero_trabajador_pilates) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT COD_IMP_FK FOREIGN KEY (codigo_sala) REFERENCES SALAS(codigo) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: No se puede hacer un UPDATE con un GROUP BY, tendras que buscar otra manera de hacer eso que buscas

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el esquema de las tablas (usa `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tabla>`)? No creo que almacenes los descuentos y los usuarios en la misma tabla, ¿verdad? Se puede hacer lo que deseas, pero no es la manera correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tendría un `GROUP BY` en una consulta del tipo `UPDATE`? ¿Acaso si quitas el `GROUP BY` la consulta no hace ya lo esperado?

Comment: Ya estoy casi, pero me asalta una duda.. no veo por ningún sitio el campo `YEAR`.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que la actualización de datos no soporta el uso de `GROUP BY` [tal y como puedes ver en la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Donde `table_reference` puede ser una o varias tablas unidas por `JOIN` [como puede leerse en la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

Por lo que tu consulta, ajustándose a la sintaxis definida en la documentación, podría ser la siguiente:

```
UPDATE CLIENTE c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) n_citas, DNI_cliente
  FROM CITA cc
  WHERE YEAR(fecha) = 2022
  GROUP BY DNI_cliente
) citas ON citas.DNI_cliente = c.DNI
SET descuento = descuento + 5
WHERE citas.n_citas > 3
  descuento < 60
```

La consulta propuesta está formada por la tabla `CLIENTE` más una consulta que obtiene todas las citas que tuvo cada cliente en el año 2022:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) n_citas, DNI_cliente
FROM CITA cc
WHERE YEAR(fecha) = 2022
GROUP BY DNI_cliente
```

Por lo que ahora podemos incluir en el `WHERE` el valor obtenido del `COUNT(*)` cuyo campo, por sencillez, he llamado `n_citas`.

PD: Puedes ver la consulta en funcionamiento en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vp2R4dMv2mkg8fmEDfXbBw/1

Comment: ¿No falta la condición *"siempre y cuando no tengan ya un descuento superior a 60"*?

Comment: @OscarGarcia  correcto, falta la condición siempre y cuando el descuento superior 60

Comment: Gracias a los dos. Sí, falta, creo que lo importante era solucionar el problema del `GROUP BY`, por eso me olvidé de ese detalle. Edito para completar la respuesta.